# Helper Code Igniter inside smarty template

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

Is this possible if I put my form_helper with array parameter in my smarty template.

this is my method of my controller:

```
function input($pIntBookId = 0) {
   $this->load->model('m_books');
   if($this->input->post('mysubmit')){
       if($this->input->post('id')){

           $this->m_books->entryUpdate();

       }else{
           $this->m_books->entryInsert();
       }
   }
   $arrData = $this->m_books->general();
   if((int)$pIntBookId>0){
       $strQuery = $this->m_books->getId($pIntBookId);
       $arrData['idxFid']['value'] = $strQuery['book_id'];
       $arrData['idxFtitle']['value'] = $strQuery['book_nm'];
       $arrData['idxFauthor']['value'] = $strQuery['book_aut'];
       $arrData['idxFpublisher']['value'] = $strQuery['book_pub'];
       $arrData['idxFyear']['value'] = $strQuery['book_year'];
       if($strQuery['book_st']=='yes'){
           $arrData['idxFavailable']['checked'] = true;
       }else{
           $arrData['idxFavailable']['checked'] = false;
       }
       $arrData['idxFsummary']['value'] = $strQuery['book_ds'];
   }
   $this->mysmarty->assign('arrData',$arrData);
   $this->mysmarty->view('v_booksinput.php');
}
```

Is this possible..? :

```
<td>{php} echo form_input($idxFtitle);{/php}</td>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just assign a Smarty template from CI, then output it? Such as, `$this->mysmarty->assign('idxFtitle', $arrData['idxFtitle']['value']);`

Comment: so i must assign all index of my array
I just want once assigning like that

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can send a variable to a template (`assign`ing a variable), or, you can embed PHP into the template. The first method *should* be the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

You can write own [smarty-function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.function.tpl) which does what you want.

```
{function name="my_input" data}
<input name="{data['value']}"></input>
{/function}
```